# Order in linking 2+ static libraries with Android NDK toolchain

Tags: android, android-ndk, linkage, dynamic-library

This is more of a general curiosity.

Supposedly I have several libraries which are of static type: A, B and C. Now I want to link another library which uses `ABC` into a shared library D.

Let's assume this is the correct way to link them:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := A B C
```

What happens when I change the previous line into this:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := A B C A B C
```

Will the `ABC` libraries be used twice in linkage or something else happens underneath?

Answer (score 0):

The linker packaged with the NDK is smart enough to deal with this, though I suspect it may add some link time while it figures it all out.